# why does the value of this factorial change when called by a function that SHOULD calculate the value of e

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double precision = 0;
    printf("\ninsert number\n");
    while(precision < 1){
        scanf("%lf",&precision);
    }
    printf("the value of e with precision of %.0lf is %lf",precision,e(precision));
    return 0;
}

int fact(int num){
    int ris = 1;
    for(int i = num;i > 0;i--){
        ris = ris * i;
    }
    printf("res=%d\n",ris);
    return ris;
}

int e(double precision){
    double valE = 1;
    for(double i = precision;i > 0 ;i--){
        valE = valE + 1/fact(i);
        printf("\nsame res:%.1lf\n",fact(i));
    }
    return (double)valE;
}
```

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bQFT.png)

i know there is an answer for that but my problem is the comunication between the 2 functions, i know i could solve it by slapping everything inside the main()

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text. Your program output is text. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I don't understand what this program is supposed to do, but maybe `e` should return a `double` rather than an `int`?  And maybe `main` should be moved below `e` so that you're not implicitly declaring anything?

Comment: Never use float numbers as loop iterators. A little bird whispered that floating point numbers are inaccurate...

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: as soon as i substitute the int e function as double e,  it stops compiling, figured simply identifying the return ad double was supposed to do the work

Comment: If you get error messages, show them. If you get an error message after changing return value of `e` to `double` that is because you probably ignored another warning or error message about implicitely declaring your function. Make sure you provide a valid prototype for `e` **before** you call it.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues:

- format specifiers (for `scanf` and `printf`) must match the arguments
- don't use floating point types as counters
- if you divide one integer by another integer, the result will be an integer that is trucated. If you want the result to be a floating point type, you need to convert at least one of the operands to a floating point type.
- you need to declare the functions you use (`fact` and `e`) before using them, or just put them before `main`, like below.

You want this, explanations in the comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fact(int num) {
  int ris = 1;
  for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    ris = ris * i;
  }
  printf("res=%d\n", ris);
  return ris;
}

double e(int precision) {
  double valE = 1;
  for (int i = precision; i > 0; i--) {  // use int for loop counters
    valE = valE + 1.0 / fact(i);         // use `1.0` instead of `1`, otherwise an 
                                         // integer division will be performed
    printf("\nsame res: %d\n", fact(i)); // use %d for int^, not %llf
  }
  return valE;                           // (double) cast is useless
}

// put both functions e and fact before main, so they are no longer
// declared implicitely

int main()
{
  int precision = 0;                  // precision should be an int
  printf("\ninsert number\n");
  while (precision < 1) {
    scanf("%d", &precision);          // use %d for int
  }
  printf("the value of e with precision of %d is %lf", precision, e(precision));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the 1.0 was the missed factor, thank you very much. i started adding double instead of int everywhere due to the program not working and me not knowing why

Comment: @user21000968 Always compile with warnings enabled and consider warnings as errors. Your original code has lots of warnings.

Comment: and integer overflow in `fact` for (on my systen) `num > 12`

Comment: @Bodo `fact` should probably return a `long long int` for preceision > 12.